# Approach to prove the factorial on LHS to the RHS?

Tags: factorial, provability

## I am brushing up my factorial solving skills, and I came across these two problems-

**1)** Prove that

## $11\cdot 12\cdot 13\cdot ...\cdot 30=30!/10!$

which I solved as-

> $=11\cdot 12\cdot 13\cdot ...\cdot 30$
>
> $=(1\cdot 2\cdot 3...\cdot 10\cdot 11\cdot 12\cdot 13\cdot ...\cdot 30)/(1\cdot 2\cdot 3\cdot ...\cdot 10)$
>
> $=30!/10!$

Am I correct here?

**2)** Prove that

## $(2n)!/n!=2^n\cdot (2n-1)\cdot (2n-3)\cdot (2n-5)....\cdot  5\cdot  3 \cdot  1$

which I tried to solve as-

> $=2n\cdot (2n-1)\cdot (2n-2)\cdot (2n-3)\cdot (2n-4)..../n!$
>
> $=2n\cdot (2n)^n\cdot n!\cdot (1\cdot 3\cdot 5.....)/n!$  [Separating the odd and even]
>
> $=2n\cdot (2n-1)\cdot (2n-3)\cdot (2n-5)...$
>    [Combining back the (2n) and odd values and canceling n!/n!]

This is as far as I could go with this problem, can anyone guide on how to achieve the LHS=RHS for this sum?

Comment: Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to format your question. It is barely legible in its current state.

Comment: A more pedantically correct answer for the second problem should involve induction.  Also, note that `2n!` many people would interpret as $2\cdot (n!)$ rather than $(2n)!$.

Comment: As an aside, $(2n-1)(2n-3)(2n-5)\cdots 5\cdot 3\cdot 1$ is more commonly written using [double factorial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_factorial) notation as $(2n-1)!!$   Also worth mentioning is that $11\cdot 12\cdot 13\cdots 29\cdot 30$ can be written more simply as $11^{\overline{20}}$ or as $30\frac{20}{~}$ using [Rising and Falling factorial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Falling_and_rising_factorials) notations respectively.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The proof for $1)$ is nice. Then at $2)$ you have

$$\frac{\color{red}(2n\color{red})!}{n!}=2n\cdot (2n-1)\cdot (2n-2)\cdot (2n-3)\cdot (2n-4)\cdot ...\cdot 2\cdot 1/n!$$

Now separating the odd and the even factors.

$$\underbrace{2n\cdot (2n-2)\cdot (2n-4)\cdot (2n-6)\cdot \ldots 4\cdot 2}_{\textrm{n factors}}\cdot (2n-1)\cdot (2n-3)\cdot (2n-5)\cdot...\cdot 3\cdot 1/n!$$

$$2^n\cdot \color{blue}{n\cdot (n-1)\cdot (n-2)\cdot (n-3)\cdot \ldots 2\cdot 1}\cdot (2n-1)\cdot (2n-3)\cdot (2n-5)\cdot...\cdot 3\cdot 1/\color{blue}{n!}$$

Cancelling out $\color{blue}{n!}$

$$2^n\cdot (2n-3)\cdot (2n-5)\cdot (2n-1)\cdot...\cdot 3\cdot 1$$

Comment: got it!, by simplification 2^n  is multiplied to all n!(or even) values. Thanks!!!

Comment: That nice and right. You´re welcome.

Answer (score 0):

For the second one,
and similar ones,
I like to use the product notation.

$\begin{array}\\
\dfrac{(2n)!}{n!}
&=\dfrac{\prod_{k=1}^{2n}k}{\prod_{k=1}^{n}k}\\
&=\dfrac{\prod_{k=1}^{n}(2k)\prod_{k=1}^{n}(2k-1)}{\prod_{k=1}^{n}k}
\qquad\text{split into even and odd parts}\\
&=\dfrac{2^n\prod_{k=1}^{n}k\prod_{k=1}^{n}(2k-1)}{\prod_{k=1}^{n}k}
\qquad\text{separate out 2}\\
&=2^n\prod_{k=1}^{n}(2k-1)\\
\end{array}
$

Note that,
since

$\begin{array}\\
\dfrac{(2n)!}{n!}
&=\dfrac{\prod_{k=1}^{2n}k}{\prod_{k=1}^{n}k}\\
&=\prod_{k=n+1}^{2n}k\\
\end{array}
$

we have
$\prod_{k=n+1}^{2n}k
=2^n\prod_{k=1}^{n}(2k-1)
$.